# NoMethodError in Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Having some issues in following Chap 6 of book 'Beginning Rails 4'

Table Schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160304183431) do

  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "published_at"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.string   "excerpt"
    t.string   "location"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "articles_categories", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "article_id"
    t.integer "category_id"
  end

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.date     "birthday"
    t.text     "bio"
    t.string   "color"
    t.string   "twitter"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

Have seeded the seeds.rb file with this:

```
user = User.create :email => 'mary@example.com', :password => 'guessit'
Category.create [{:name => 'Programming'},
                 {:name => 'Event'},
                 {:name => 'Travel'},
                 {:name => 'Music'},
                 {:name => 'TV'}]
```

Then went into the console:

```
 article = Article.last
 #<Article id: 5, title: "Advanced Active Record", body: "Models need to relate to each other. In the real w...", published_at: "2016-03-03 00:00:00", created_at: "2016-03-04 06:35:27", updated_at: "2016-03-04 06:35:27", excerpt: nil, location: nil, user_id: nil>
 category = Category.find_by_name('Programming')
 #<Category id: 1, name: "Programming", created_at: "2016-03-04 18:40:57", updated_at: "2016-03-04 18:40:57">
 article.categories << category
```

It's the last line that gets me in trouble. Every time I attempt to do `article.categories << category`, I get this message everytime: `NoMethodError: undefined method categories' for #<Article:0x007fdbc333a328>`

Why?

EDIT

Article Model

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :title, :body

    belongs_to :user
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories

    def long_title
        "#{title} - #{published_at}"
    end

end
```

Category Model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
end
```

Comment: What do your Article and Category models look like?

Comment: do you have your associations defined in the models? I.e. in class Article has_and_belongs_to_many :categories ? and has_and_belongs_to_many :articles in Categories?

Comment: @RickRunyon, just added that info.

Comment: Creating the schema is half of the work. The other half is defining your `has_many` relationship. I'd recommend avoiding the really old-style `has_and_belongs_to_many` with no ID column as those can be problematic when used for anything other than the most trivial of associations.

Comment: @osman, the models do have that. just added that info above.

Comment: @tadman, oh, wow. I had no idea. I'm just trying to follow along with the book to learn it.

Comment: @tadman, why is it problematic?

Comment: `has_many` with the `:through` option gives you a lot more control over the relationship records themselves, and when you start to add data to the relationship it doesn't get mangled into the model itself. `has_and_belongs_to_many` is an artifact from Rails 1.0 that's a lot more limited in how you can use it, so to put it in a new application is usually a mistake.

Comment: exit the console go back in and try again :-)

Comment: @osman, hee, just did based on tadman's `reload!` comment.

Comment: ugh, wish I realized that i was supposed to reload or exit!

Answer (score 0):

Besides this table

```
create_table "articles_categories", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "article_id"
  t.integer "category_id"
end
```

You also need an index:

```
add_index "articles_categories", ["article_id", "category_id"], name: "index_articles_categories_on_article_id_and_category_id", unique: true, using: :btree
```

This way, rails's magic will be able to link your Articles and Categories. There may be some misspellings, but you get the idea.

Comment: wait, are you saying that just having that table wasn't enough? I also needed an index? But then why didn't the book say to do that?

Comment: Indexes help with performance. You can struggle along without them, but as soon as you have non-trivial amounts of data your database will become cripplingly slow.

Comment: Since this is a join table, you can also set `null: false` on both of those columns.

Comment: @JonasMeinerz, so, this will solve the `NoMethodError` message if I add the index? I know indexes help with performance issues, but I didn't realize it would resolve this particular error.

Comment: The index doesn't help with the method. It's just a performance optimization.

Comment: Remember when you add methods to your models you need to `reload!` your console or it will be out of date.

Comment: @tadman, it was the `reload!` that was apprently lacking here. that solved the probelm.

Comment: When doing testing like this, the best way to do exercise your code is through model tests. Write those first and run them over and over until things work out. The model code is reloaded for each test run which helps a lot.

Comment: @tadman, I have no idea how to test. I'm in the process of learning ROR first.

Comment: Rails is all about test-driven development, so if you want to learn more about the correct way of doing it, start there. Write a test that *should* work, then write the code to make it work. For someone who's starting out, writing the test first sets a clear expectation of the goal. It's too easy to get lost writing code with no actual purpose if you don't start with tests. Every model comes with a test stub in `tests/models` that serves as a template and there's a [testing guide for Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html) in the core docs.

Comment: This is totally, totally wrong. Indexes have **nothing** to do with model associations and a lack of an index cannot possibly produce the symptoms described in the question. @user27307254534534534543675765 Regarding all of your above questions, no, this answer will not in any way help you.

Comment: @tadman, hey, thanks for reminding me that I need to be test-oriented. will start trying to learn some basics today.

Comment: @meagar, no worries. problem was solved via tadman's comment of `reload!`. it was good to be reminded of indexes as well though! =) happy friday! (at least where I am at, it's friday!)